# Data point inside 2-D contour line

Tags: matlab

I have used:

```
[C,h] = contour(x,y,z,v,'LineWidth',2)
```

then I have plotted different data into the plot using:

```
plot(param_final_r_s_cgga_bundle292(:,1),param_final_r‌​_s_cgga_bundle292(:,‌​2),'k.','markersize'‌​,4)
```

Now I want to know the number of above points inside each contour coming from `param_final_r_s_cgga_bundle292` file.

When I use your command:

```
sum(param_final_r_s_cgga_bundle292(:,1)<c1 && param_final_r_s_cgga_bundle292(:,2)>c2)
```

I get error report:

> Undefined function or variable '`c1`'. Error in (line 39) 
>      
> `sum(param_final_r_s_cgga_bundle292(:,1)<c1 && param_final_r_s_cgga_bundle292(:,2)>c2)`

Comment: I assume you do not have the "Z" value of this data points?

Comment: Yes I have x, y and z value. Using these I have generated 2-D contour plot. Again I have plotted other data on this plot. Now I want to count number of new data point inside each contour.

Comment: sooo  `sum( points(:,3)<c1 && points(:,3)>c2)`  for each contour gap `[c1 c2]` ?

Comment: It's not working.

Comment: I have used:[C,h] = contour(x,y,z,v,'LineWidth',2)  then I have plotted different data into the plot using:plot(param_final_r_s_cgga_bundle292(:,1),param_final_r_s_cgga_bundle292(:,2),'k.','markersize',4) now I want to know the number of above points inside each contour coming from param_final_r_s_cgga_bundle292 file. when I use your command :sum(param_final_r_s_cgga_bundle292(:,1)<c1 && param_final_r_s_cgga_bundle292(:,2)>c2) I got erro report : Undefined function or variable 'c1'.
Error in (line 39)
sum(param_final_r_s_cgga_bundle292(:,1)<c1 &&
param_final_r_s_cgga_bundle292(:,2)>c2)

Comment: Please, edit your original question with the information, do not add it to a comment. Also read [mcve]